# An etale cover of a semiperfect ring

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, etale-cohomology

Assume that $R$ is a semiperfect ring in characteristic $p$, i.e the frobenius is surjective on $R$. I think one can prove that an etale cover of $R$ should again be semiperfect by considering the basic etale maps similar to the fact that an algebraic extension of a perfect field is again perfect. Is this true and has anyone a better proof or a reference for this fact?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is true.

**Definition.** We say that a map $A\to B$ of (commutative) $\mathbb F_p$-algebras is *relatively perfect* (resp. *relatively semiperfect* if the relative Frobenius map $\varphi_{B/A}\colon B\otimes_{A,\varphi_A}A\to B$ is an isomorphism (resp. surjective).

The result that you want is a consequence of the following:

**Lemma.** A composite of two composable relatively semiperfect maps of $\mathbb F_p$-algebras is still relatively semiperfect.

**Proof.** Let $A\to B\to C$ be two composable relatively semiperfect maps of $\mathbb F_p$-algebras. Then the relative Frobenius map $\varphi_{C/A}\colon C\otimes_{A,\varphi_A}A\to C$ coincides with the composite
$$
C\otimes_{A,\varphi_A}A=C\otimes_BB\otimes_{B,\varphi_{B/A}}A\xrightarrow{1_C\otimes\varphi_{B/A}}C\otimes_{B,\varphi_{B/A}}B\xrightarrow{\varphi_{C/B}}C.
$$
Q.E.D.

**Proposition.** **([Stacks project, Tag 0F6W](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0F6W))** Every weakly étale map of $\mathbb F_p$-algebras is relatively perfect.